# Maximum principle for a strong solution to non-homogenous Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, maximum-principle, poissons-equation

I am searching for a reference for this apparently well known fact (the part below Theorem 1.1 in the picture i.e. the equation $(6)$):

[image]

This screenshot is from [https://math.aalto.fi/~astalak2/files/pucci_conjecture.pdf](https://math.aalto.fi/%7Eastalak2/files/pucci_conjecture.pdf). Here the operator $\mathcal{L}_Au=\text{Tr}(A(x)D^2u)$ (this can be found on the linked paper before Theorem 1.1). I am interested on this refence since I need this kind of maximum principle for the Poisson equation $\Delta u=f$ where the solution $u$ is in $W^{2,p}(\Omega)$ and the function $f\in L^p(\Omega)$, $p>n/2$.

Thus if anyone would know a refence, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the paper you linked the sentence immediately before this theorem cites Theorem 9.1 in Gilbarg and Trudinger. Is there a reason why this is not a suitable reference?

Comment: @JackT This theorem you mentioned is the same as Theorem 1.1. in the picture, thus it is not a reference for equation (6). Or am I missing something here?